# Using regex, get a string after a character, special case

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm using python with regex to read a file and get a list of string after a character (/).

For example:

```
text = "Youngblood /Pop Midnight/R&B Thunder/Rock"
re.findall(r'/([^\s]+)', text)
```

would return

```
['Pop', 'R&B', 'Rock']
```

Now, let's say if there is a special case where there is two characters '/' in a substring,

```
abc\/def/this
```

or

```
abc\/def\/ghi/this
```

the regex will not work correctly (as I wanted) and return 'def/this' or 'def/ghi/this'.

The correct output is "this". How do I fix the regex to work with that special case?

Comment: What should be correct output for special case? I'm confused.

Comment: Is there always space between strings? Like Midnight/R&B 'space' Thunder/Rock etc.

Comment: @RaoslawSzamszur I editted the question. I only want to get the string after the last '/'

Comment: @RaoslawSzamszur there always be a space for each substrings need to be applied the regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
re.findall(r'/([^\s/]+(?!\S))', text)
```

returns

```
['Pop', 'R&B', 'Rock', 'ghj']
```

You need a lookahead because you want to inspect the character after your match. You cannot use `(?=\s)` (which will match the space) because then the last item will be skipped. The construction `(?!\S)` means ***not*** *not* a space, which matches a space but also End Of String.

Answer (score 1):

If there is always space between strings you can do it even without regexp.

```
text = "Youngblood/Pop Midnight/R&B Thunder/Rock abc/def/ghj"
output = []

for item in text.split(" "):
    output.append(item.split("/")[-1])
```

Output:

```
['Pop', 'R&B', 'Rock', 'ghj']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not hell bent on using *all* `regex` to complete the exact purpose, you can combine what you already have with this list comprehension:

```
targets = [e.split('/')[-1] for e in re.findall('/([^\s]+)', text)]
```